# Add Value From Recordset + Value From Input Box Through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, excel-2013

I have an input box where a user is inputting a value.  I want to take the value that the user is inputting and add it to a value that is being read from a recordset.  I have attempted this syntax, which is not throwing an error for me, however the issue is, that the value is not being added to the value from the recordset.  What should I alter in order for the simple addition calculation to occur?

```
Public Function AddToValue()
Dim value2 As Variant
Dim ExportRecordSet As DAO.Recordset
Dim excelWS As Object
Dim xl As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim TemplateWB As String
Dim row As Integer

value2 = InputBox("Enter Value To Add:", "VBA InputBox Function")

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
TemplateWB = "C:\Test\Testwb.xlsx"
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
Set excelWS = wb.Worksheets(1)
excelWS.Name = "AddedFromCode"
xl.Application.Visible = True

Set ExportRecordSet = db.OpenRecordset(" Select Total FROM localtesttable;")

If Not ExportRecordSet.EOF Then
While Not ExportRecordSet.EOF

    excelWS.Cells(row, 5).Value = ExportRecordSet("Total")+value2

Wend
End If

wb.SaveAs 

wb.Close

End Function
```

**EDIT**
Per the comment from @KenWhite - I will clarify exactly what I am wanting to achieve in the syntax above:

> 1) Get userinput for value2 
>  2) read the value from the field Total
>  3) write to Excel the value from the field total + value2

**EDIT #2**
Link where I saw to use both the `If Not EOF` and the `While Not EOF`

[Looping DAO Recordsets](http://www.accessallinone.com/looping-through-a-recordset/)

Comment: Much of your code makes no sense. `row = 1`, open dataset, `row = row + 1` is useless. So is `If Not EOF then While not EOF`; the if statement is uselessly redundant. If you're at Eof then the while will not execute, so there's no need for the if at all. It's unclear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @KenWhite - I am wanting to 1) Get userinput for value2 - 2) read the value from the field Total, 3) write to Excel the value from the field total + value2

Comment: @KenWhite - in response to your ? about using If ... EOF and While ... EOF - to my understanding, you would 1st Execute the if ...EOF to verify that the ExportRecordSet has records.  -> the While ... EOF loops through the records, and if the end of ExportRecordSet is reached this method will return true and leave the while loop.  I used this as a basis for the syntax, is this off the mark on how things should be coded?    http://www.accessallinone.com/looping-through-a-recordset/

Comment: No. `While not EOF` will test to see if there are records, so it knows whether it needs to enter the loop at all. As I said, you don't need both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to advance the row and the recordset:

```
Public Function AddToValue()

    Dim ExportRecordSet As DAO.Recordset
    Dim excelWS As Object
    Dim xl As Object
    Dim wb As Object
    Dim TemplateWB As String
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim value2 As String

    value2 = InputBox("Enter Value To Add:", "VBA InputBox Function")

    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    TemplateWB = "C:\Test\Testwb.xlsx"
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
    Set excelWS = wb.Worksheets(1)
    excelWS.Name = "AddedFromCode"
    xl.Application.Visible = True

    Set ExportRecordSet = db.OpenRecordset("Select Total FROM localtesttable;")
    ' Set start row.
    row = 1
    While Not ExportRecordSet.EOF        
        excelWS.Cells(row, 5).Value = ExportRecordSet("Total") + Val(value2)
        row = row + 1
        ExportRecordset.MoveNext
    Wend

    wb.SaveAs 
    wb.Close

End Function
```